# Remove H1 site-tittle tag from product page with a function SEO

Tags: tags, seo

How to Remove H1 site-tittle tag from product page SEO.
I only want the product-tittle tag in the H1 tag

How can i do that with a function?

https://www.jazzboekingsburo.nl/the-blueberries-james-bond-muziek/

Thanks!

Comment: This would be specific to your theme. You should speak to its author.

Comment: How do i contact him?

Comment: You haven’t even said which theme you’re using, but A. Shouldn’t assume it’s a him. B. There’s probably a link to their website on the theme in the back end of your website.

Comment: Is the storefront child theme